# "Scoped" Range Query in MarkLogic?

Tags: marklogic

Given the following document structure, I need to compose a query to find, for example, all accounts with > 500 USD.

```
{
  "account": 1, 
  "assets": [
    {
      "currency": "USD", 
      "amount": 600
    }, 
    {
      "currency": "CAD", 
      "amount": 1000
    }, 
    {
      "currency": "EUR", 
      "amount": 200
    }
  ]
}
```

Using Xpath predicate, it would be something like:

```
fn:collection()[//(currency='USD' and amount>500)]
```

However I am having trouble to create a cts query for the same purpose, leveraging range index. Naively I can create a separate path range index for each currency type but that seems to be too much.

Any suggestions? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
cts.search(cts.jsonPropertyScopeQuery('assets', 
           cts.andQuery([cts.jsonPropertyValueQuery('currency', 'USD'),
                         cts.jsonPropertyRangeQuery('amount', '>', 599.99)
                         ])
          ))
```

Comment: Thank you, Fiona. This was essentially my first attempt. Note that the range index is applied across all "amount" elements so it can return false positive. For example, what if I am looking for accounts with > 800 USD?

Comment: I am not sure if I follow. How do you mean "accounts with > 800 USD" ?  False positive can be eliminated by deploying different type of index, depending on your search criteria and document structure.

Comment: I mean if you use the query but change the the number to 800, you would still find the same document. However it would be incorrect because the account doesn't have 800 USD.

Answer (score 1):

Fiona's solution works when eliminating the false positives by running a filtered search or by indexing positions.

An alternative would be to model the data in a different way:

```
{
  "account": 1, 
  "assetsByCurrency": {
    "USD": {"amount": 600}, 
    "CAD": {"amount": 1000}, 
    "EUR": {"amount": 200}
  }
}
```

With that model, it should be possible to eliminate false positives without filtering or positions:

```
cts.search(cts.jsonPropertyScopeQuery('assetsByCurrency', 
       cts.jsonPropertyScopeQuery('USD',
                     cts.jsonPropertyRangeQuery('amount', '>', 599.99)
                     ))
      ))
```

Another possibility would be to index the assets objects with TDE and retrieve the data using the Optic API, which allows comparison filters on any column and eliminates false positives.

Hoping that helps,

Comment: With the original model, false positives can arise when the range query on `599.99` matches the amount in an asset with the EUR currency and the value query on `USD` matches the currency in a different asset. The false positives can be eliminated by using TDE to project rows, by positional indexing, or by changing the model.